# SQL Subqueries for Attendance This Month and Last Month

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to craft a query for the following situation, but I just can't seem to get it from the conceptual to the actual.

I have three tables:

- Profile (ID, First_Name, Last_Name)
- Event (ID, Date)
- Attendance (Profile_ID, Event_ID)

I'm trying to get a list of profiles who have attended both this month and last month.

So far, I've thought of doing some kind of a count for both months, and only selecting them when they're greater than 1, but I haven't quite gotten it to work yet.

Something like:

```
SELECT * FROM Profile
LEFT OUTER JOIN Attendance ON Profile.ID = Attendance.Profile_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Event ON Attendance.Event_ID = Event.ID
WHERE [subquery to confirm attendance of this Profile_ID in this month/year > 1]
AND [subquery to confirm attendance of this Profile_ID in last month/year > 1]
```

So the first question is whether or not I'm thinking about the problem correctly and am moving in a good direction. The second question is how to do those subqueries properly - I can easily make something like `SELECT * FROM Attendance WHERE MONTH(Date) = 12 AND YEAR(Date) = 2016`, but that's would return a list of all attendances. What I really want is a list of only the attendances for each ID individually - so when I'm looking at ID 4, I want to check to see if that particular ID has an attendance this month and last month, but I'm not sure how to add that to the WHERE clause.

Comment: 1) yes - that's one method. Another is to count distinct months having a total equal to the number of arguments. For 2), see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FIRST OF ALL AVOID USING KEYWORDS IN COLUMN NAMES as you did with Date `Event(ID,Date)`
To answer your first question: it is logical to think that way and it is possible to get it. About the direction, I think the left join approach is ok so the main problem is on the filter. 
Now since the 2nd attendance in the month does not matter we extract only the month from the event date so that we get such a record as duplicate `EXTRACT(MONTH FROM Events.event_date`. Now the `DATEDIFF()` wouldn't be appropriate so we use the `MONTH()` to get the current and last month events. 
    `MONTH(CURRENT_DATE) - MONTH(Events.event_date) = 0` gives event in current month
    `MONTH(CURRENT_DATE) - MONTH(Events.event_date) = 1` gives event in last month
    `MONTH(CURRENT_DATE) - MONTH(Events.event_date) = -11` gives event in December if current month is january (i.e 1-12=-11)

This will give a list of profiles for those who attended in distinct months. So the next thing is from that set select only those who appear twice. Do it with the `GROUP BY x.id HAVING COUNT(x.id) = 2`

so you should have

```
SELECT x.id,x.first_name,x.last_name FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT Profile.ID,Profile.first_name,Profile.last_name,Attendance.Profile_ID, EXTRACT(MONTH FROM Events.event_date) AS event_date FROM 
Profiles
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Attendance ON Profile.ID = Attendance.Profile_ID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Events ON Attendance.Event_ID = Events.ID
    WHERE (

          (MONTH(CURRENT_DATE) - MONTH(Events.event_date)) = 0 
          OR 
          (MONTH(CURRENT_DATE) - MONTH(Events.event_date)) = 1 
          OR 
          (MONTH(CURRENT_DATE) - MONTH(Events.event_date)) = -11

          ) 
  ) AS x  GROUP BY x.id HAVING COUNT(x.id) = 2
```

Comment: Regarding the use of the keyword, you're right - I actually changed it to "Date" as a form of anonymization, the actual name is something like dateOfClass or something like that. Regarding the query, would this not include people who came twice this month but zero times the previous month? You may cover that in your last sentence but I'm not clear on it